# request.remote_ip returns wrong ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip-address

I have logging on my website, and i see logs for different people (with different UserAgent strings).

I'm sure, that they have different ip, but all the log records having the same ip.

I use request.remote_ip to store it in DB.

I don't have Apache as front-end. I just have Mongrel.

The question is - Why they are the same ?

Answer (score 3):

If both users are behind the same proxy server or use the same internet provider, they may appear to have the same IP address. The IP that is seen at the web server is not the IP address of the individual PC, it's the address of the connection being used.

Comment: I agree... I would just add NAT to the list as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a load balancer, particularly a non-transparent load balancer, your server will see the IP address of the load balancer.  Often times the load balancer will throw the the original remote ip address into a HTTP header.